# Confused about caching solution: MemCache, Varnished, mod_cache, else?

Tags: varnish, memcached, mod-cache

I have a very heavy site in my server. The load of the server is always about 30-50 and sometimes it become even 150 and server work really hard. I'm looking for a caching solution that can increase performance of server and decrease the server load.

But I do not know which caching solution I should use? By the way I'm using Drupal CMS and I have WHM/CPanel

Here are options which I found:
1- Memcached
2- Varnish
3- Apache mod_cache

Can someone please give me some comparison or guidance about these platforms? Does mod_cache of Apache work as good as say Varnish? Because installing and configuring Varnish is not a bit complicated in cPanel / WHM. Although I read very good reviews about Varnish.

I'm looking for the best cache solution which can configured straightforward and not complicated. I would appreciate any help or comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Here are options which I found: 1- Memcached 2- Varnish 3- Apache
>   mod_cache

Caveats: Do you know why your load is so high?  If the load is caused
by high CPU load required to generate dynamic content, and you're
able to serve that content from a cache, than a caching solution may
help you.  But if the load is caused by i/o contention, or if you're
serving personalized content that isn't amendable to caching, then a
caching solution may not help much.

In general, a cache will need a big chunk of memory in order to be
effective.  If your system is already memory constrained, then putting
caching software on it could conceivably exacerbate your problem.

- Memcached

  Memcached by itself won't help you.  That is, unlike Varnish and
  Apache's mod_cache, Memcached is not something you can simply stand
  up in front of an existing application.

  Memcached is a very fast key/value datastore that can be used by
  applications to speed up a variety of operations.  A common example
  is a database that needs to make database queries: if it's okay to
  cache the results for some amount of time, the results may be served
  much faster by memcached than by the backend datbase.

  If you're server load is largely the result of custom code, then
  modifying your code to take advantage of memcached can yield a
  substantial benefit.
- Varnish and Apache's mod_cache

  Both of these can be used to accelerate the delivery of dynamic
  content.

  Of the two, Varnish is a specialized tool designed *only* as a
  content accelerator.  It only does one thing, but by reputation it
  does it very well.  The configuration language is a C-subset that
  gets compiled and loaded into the running Varnish process; this
  isn't good or bad by itself but I prefer more declarative languages.

  Apache's mod_cache can also be used as a content accelerator.  There
  are two advantages to mod_cache:

  - If you're already running Apache, you'll be familiar with the
    configuration used by mod_cache.
  - You can combine mod_cache with other Apache modules (e.g.,
    mod_rewrite and mod_header) to create a very flexible
    configuration.

  On the other hand, your performance may not be as good as that
  provided by Varnish.  I don't actually have any numbers to back this
  up, but they're probably out there (look for them -- don't take my
  word for it!).

  Both products work best if you tune your backend application to
  provide cache-friendly content.  This means appropriate caching
  headers, no cookies on cacheable content, appropriate max-age or
  expiration headers, etc.

Make sure you understand your problem first: figure out what's causing
the high load.  Then try one or more of these solutions and see what
happens.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer and great information you provided.

Comment: In the particular case of Drupal though, memcache itself _will_ help. Just enable the [memcache](https://drupal.org/project/memcache) module, and Drupal can utilize it as a drop-in solution.